# Com exception creating Redemption SafePostItem C#

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

I am using Redemption 4.4 dll and I came across a very strange bug. The biggest problem is that I am not able to reproduce it, but I keep getting bug report from other employees.

The error they get is : 
The recovery of the COM class factory for component with CLSID { 11E2BC0C - 5D4F - 4E0C - B438-501FFE05A382 } failed due to the following error: Error 800703e7 during a paging operation . (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703e7 ) .

The line that throws the error is : 
    `Redemption.SafePostItem postItem = new Redemption.SafePostItem();`

The dll is stored on a network path and we are using regsvr32.exe to register it.
    `regsvr32.exe -s [NetworkPath]`

We are using an x86 version of the dll, of outlook 2010 and I am compiling my code in x86.

The users can run this code multiple times without problem, then it happens once and if they try again the bug is gone without changing anything.

I know this is not much to go with but its all I got for now. If I find a way to reproduce it, I will update this post.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The dll is stored on a network path

Yes, funny things can happen when you do that.  Like that Windows error 999, getting a page-fault when the operating system tries to load code from the DLL but the network connection went down.  And yes, "happens once, not if they try again" is also strongly correlated to a flaky network connection.

There is not anything you can do about a poor network connection, it is not a programming problem.  Other than pointing the LAN administrator or your users to this post.  And *strongly* recommending them to copy the DLL to a local drive.  The quick fix, getting a bad network repaired usually takes a while.

Comment: After talking with the IT department, there was indeed a network problem on our side. Since this problem has been fixed, I had no other bug report from the users. I think we can safely assume that this was the root cause of the problem. Thank you.